# Outlook 2019 stopped working

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am a licensed user of Office 2019. My Outlook stopped working one day, and displays these error messages:

> Outlook cannot log on. Verify you are connected to the network and are
> using the proper server and mailbox name. The Microsoft Exchange
> information service in your profile is missing required information.
> Modify your profile to ensure that you are using the correct Microsoft
> Exchange information service.

Second message (after I close the first message)

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The
> set of folders cannot be opened. The information store could not be
> opened.

It was working one day and broken the next day. I did not change anything and I have the correct passwords for all my Microsoft email accounts (I can access those accounts in the browser and on my cell phone).

What is happening, and how can I fix this?

Using Windows 10, latest patches.

Comment: Asking a search engine leads to the [following hints](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4b573bd8-623b-44d6-b7ee-a9c428fccb2d/cannot-start-microsoft-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-window-the-set-of-folders-cannot-be-opened?forum=outlook)

Comment: Make sure you have a backup of your email, then go to Control Panel, Mail and remove the Outlook Profile (removes your account). Restart, make a new Outlook Profile and then try Outlook again.

Comment: @John Please enter this as an answer, so I can give you credit.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Thanks and I hope you will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Outlook 2019 is working well but you cannot log in, you need to re-create your Outlook Profile.

Make sure you have a backup of your email, then go to Control Panel, Mail and remove the Outlook Profile (removes your account).

Restart, make a new Outlook Profile and then try Outlook again.  It should work at that point.

Comment: Some links that can help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/after-migration-to-office-365-outlook-doesn-t-connect-or-web-services-don-t-work-3d9df009-597b-5d75-460c-4b7c64c833a1 , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange/troubleshoot/outlook-issues/issues-when-using-autodiscover-service , https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-2016-outlook-cannot-log-on-verify-you-are/20d53c1b-1877-415a-9211-def9d61416fd

Comment: Good sharing! That's useful.